# Given bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ and $B$, find bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A \cup B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two countable sets and consider that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ and $g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$.

I have to find a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A \cup B$ involving both $f$ and $g$.

I thought of split  $\mathbb{N}$ in even and odd numbers using $f(\frac{n}{2})$ if $n$ is even and $g(\frac{n-1}{2})$ if $n$ is odd, but it doesn't work because I can just prove the onto property, I can't guarantee it will be one-to-one because $A \cap B$ may be non empty (for instance, it might happen that $f(2)$ would be equal $g(5)$...)

In general, all the strategies I've tried to construct such bijection have failed because $A \cap B$ may be non empty.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate the elements of $A\cup B$ in the order in which they appear in $f(1),g(1),f(2),g(2),\ldots$; that is, form the surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $A\cup B$ that you formed and then "compact" it my removing the duplicates.

Comment: thanks for answering. How can I compact it?

Comment: @user3794796: I'm not sure I understand the question. I thought this was about defining a bijection. Do you want to construct it algorithmically?

Comment: No, I don't need it. I just asked about how to compact it because I don't understand very well what do you mean...  Doing so, can I still have a closed formula to the bijection I am constructing?

Comment: @user3794796: I see. Never mind the "compacting" part if it's not clear; I just added that to make it more visualisable, but you can just use the formal definition in the first part of the sentence. No, I don't see how to get a closed form for this bijection; but I don't see one for any other bijection, either.

Comment: well, in fact, listing in that order is exactly what I did, as I described in the question: $0 \rightarrow f(\frac{0}{2}) = f(0)$;  $1 \rightarrow g(\frac{1 - 1}{2}) = g(0)$; $2 \rightarrow f(\frac{2}{2}) = f(1)$;  $3 \rightarrow g(\frac{3 - 1}{2}) = g(1)$; etc

Comment: But then, I can't prove that this function is one-to-one, because it may happen that for some $n_0$ and some $n_1$, $f(n_0) = f(n_1)$. Therefore, it seems that "compact" part is what I am missing...

Comment: @user3794796: That's not a bijection (as you noted in the question). By "enumerate them in the order in which they appear", I meant the bijection that maps $1$ to the element that appears first, $2$ to the element that appears second, $3$ to the element that appears third, etc., ignoring the elements when they appear again.

Comment: Oh, I see... Please, give some time to analyse it...